# Change alignment of plot text

Tags: r, plot, alignment, visualization

When adding text to a plot, the default position is *centered* at the specified coordinates. For example,

```
plot(1:10, 1:10)
text(x = 6, y = 1, "text")
```

[image]

In this plot, the text starts at around `x = 5, y = 1`, but I want it to be *left-aligned*, i.e. start at `x = 6, y = 1`. How can I change the alignment?
Thank you

Comment: Check out `mtext()` function: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.2/topics/mtext

Comment: So `text(x=6, y=1, "text", adj = 0)` should work.

Comment: Thank you @RonakShah !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alignment (adjustment / justification) of `text` is set by the `adj` argument. To left-align, set `adj = 0`.

From `?text`:

> `adj`: one or two values in [0, 1] which specify the x (and optionally y) adjustment (‘justification’) of the labels, with 0 for left/bottom, 1 for right/top, and 0.5 for centered. On most devices values outside [0, 1] will also work.

> `adj` allows adjustment of the text position with respect to `(x, y)`. Values of 0, 0.5, and 1 specify that `(x, y)` should align with the left/bottom, middle and right/top of the text, respectively. The default is for centered text, i.e., `adj = c(0.5, NA)`. Accurate vertical centering needs character metric information on individual characters which is only available on some devices. Vertical alignment is done slightly differently for character strings and for expressions: `adj = c(0,0)` means to left-justify and to align on the baseline for strings but on the bottom of the bounding box for expressions. This also affects vertical centering: for strings the centering excludes any descenders whereas for expressions it includes them. Using `NA` for strings centers them, including descenders.

```
plot(1:10, 1:10)
text(x = 6, y = 1, "text", adj = 0)
```

`adj = 0` will left-align the text:

[image]